# Specific bifurcations of 3D ODE system

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm looking for a list of all types of bifurcation that can exist in a 3D system of differential equations.

As it has been well described for 1D and 2D systems, I'm interested in knowing specificities created by a third dimension.